# How to redirect stdin and stdout and stderr at the same time in bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, io-redirection

I want to redirect `stdin` and `stdout` and `stderr` at the same time in `bash`, is this how it's done:

```
someProgram < stdinFile.txt > stdoutFile.txt 2> stderrFile.txt
```

Comment: @roaima I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your syntax is correct although the following equivalent one is closer to what the shell actually does:

```
< stdinFile.txt > stdoutFile.txt 2> stderrFile.txt command arguments
```

The files used for redirection are open before the command is launched, and if there is a failure in this first step, the command is not launched.